# VS2005 How to force all pointer access to be unaligned?

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2005

I have some code or better to say a complete project copied from STM32/FreeRTOS to  OMAP2430/WindowsCE platform.

In the copied C/C++ files I have some code which deals with data structures which are created and destroyed at  run time and size and address alignments totally depend on the amount of data that goes in to the data structure during the creation of each.

I don't want to use any packing/padding to make the address alignment correct but would like to use any compiler option that will allow for unaligned access of data structures.
For now I have been using `__unaligned` type modifier for data structure pointers ( `UNALIGNED` macro from `Windef.h`)

I know It can create some performance drop, but I can live with that in this particular section of code.

What I would like to know from my fellow programmers is that is there an option in Windows CE compiler settings which will force all memory accesses to unaligned. I am talking about some thing  like this https://blogs.oracle.com/d/entry/on_misaligned_memory_accesses

Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this might be what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318844/how-to-enable-armv6-unaligned-access-on-winmobile6

Answer (score 1):

I believe that on ARM, misaligned access can be a hardware error, rather than the performance drop it is on x86. Thus it might be *impossible* for the compiler to perform such an action.

Comment: Compilers for systems that don't allow unaligned accesses can read the data byte by byte and reconstruct the value. I know gcc does exactly that for ARM when strict alignment is enabled and data is loaded from an known-unaligned address, and the __unaligned keyword in the question suggests that the Windows CE compiler (whichever compiler that is) can too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

Setting particular elements to __unaligned will do it. So will:

```
# pragma pack (1)
struct x_
{
   char a;    // 1 byte
   int b;     // 4 bytes
   short c;   // 2 bytes
} MyStruct;
# pragma pack ()
```

or setting the packing on the compiler command line with /Zp1

You'll know pretty fast if your target processor supports dereferencing pointers through unaligned access - you'll get a bus error (SIGBUS) on an unaligned access if it can't support it.

You can probably get the best of both worlds, if you just copy the pointer out of the data structure before following it. Eg just assign it to a function pointer temporary.